# How to add and configure Web Performance and Load Test using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, performance-testing

I developed .Net Core web application using visual studio code. For that, I want to add and configure the "web performance and load test project". Is it possible to add and configure the web performance and load test through the Visual Studio Code? If yes, please suggest me how to done it?